# Re-organise array using Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I've got a question regarding re-organizing (is there a proper term for this?) an array in jQuery.

Below is a sample of the array in question. Basically it shows a list of video games, each game has another nested array for platforms (consoles the game is available on).

I want to change the array so as to remove the nested array and duplicate the top level.
I have been trying jQuery's $.map to no avail.

I want to get from this

```
game1
    xbox
    ps3
    PC
game2
    xbox
    wii
```

to this

```
game1, xbox
game1, ps3
game1, PC
game2, xbox
game2, wii
```

below is the actual array

```
myCallback({
    error: "OK",
    limit: 5,
    offset: 0,
    number_of_page_results: 5,
    number_of_total_results: 26,
    status_code: 1,
    results: [{
        image: {
            icon_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_avatar/8/87790/1784831-box_bf2.png",
            medium_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_medium/8/87790/1784831-box_bf2.png",
            screen_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/screen_medium/8/87790/1784831-box_bf2.png",
            small_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/8/87790/1784831-box_bf2.png",
            super_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_large/8/87790/1784831-box_bf2.png",
            thumb_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_avatar/8/87790/1784831-box_bf2.png",
            tiny_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_mini/8/87790/1784831-box_bf2.png"
        },
        name: "Battlefield 2",
        platforms: [{
            api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-94/",
            id: 94,
            name: "PC",
            site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/pc/3045-94/",
            abbreviation: "PC"
        }],
        resource_type: "game"
    }, {
        image: {
            icon_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_avatar/8/87790/2409898-box_bfbc2.png",
            medium_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_medium/8/87790/2409898-box_bfbc2.png",
            screen_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/screen_medium/8/87790/2409898-box_bfbc2.png",
            small_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/8/87790/2409898-box_bfbc2.png",
            super_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_large/8/87790/2409898-box_bfbc2.png",
            thumb_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_avatar/8/87790/2409898-box_bfbc2.png",
            tiny_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_mini/8/87790/2409898-box_bfbc2.png"
        },
        name: "Battlefield: Bad Company 2",
        platforms: [{
            api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-20/",
            id: 20,
            name: "Xbox 360",
            site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/xbox-360/3045-20/",
            abbreviation: "X360"
        }, {
            api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-35/",
            id: 35,
            name: "PlayStation 3",
            site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/playstation-3/3045-35/",
            abbreviation: "PS3"
        }, {
            api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-94/",
            id: 94,
            name: "PC",
            site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/pc/3045-94/",
            abbreviation: "PC"
        }, {
            api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-96/",
            id: 96,
            name: "iPhone",
            site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/iphone/3045-96/",
            abbreviation: "IPHN"
        }, {
            api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-121/",
            id: 121,
            name: "iPad",
            site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/ipad/3045-121/",
            abbreviation: "IPAD"
        }],
        resource_type: "game"
    }, {
        image: {
            icon_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_avatar/6/63119/1711171-battlefield_play4free.jpg",
            medium_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_medium/6/63119/1711171-battlefield_play4free.jpg",
            screen_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/screen_medium/6/63119/1711171-battlefield_play4free.jpg",
            small_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/6/63119/1711171-battlefield_play4free.jpg",
            super_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_large/6/63119/1711171-battlefield_play4free.jpg",
            thumb_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_avatar/6/63119/1711171-battlefield_play4free.jpg",
            tiny_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_mini/6/63119/1711171-battlefield_play4free.jpg"
        },
        name: "Battlefield Play4Free",
        platforms: [{
            api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-94/",
            id: 94,
            name: "PC",
            site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/pc/3045-94/",
            abbreviation: "PC"
        }],
        resource_type: "game"
    }, {
        image: {
            icon_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_avatar/3/34737/1032047-bf1942_front.jpg",
            medium_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_medium/3/34737/1032047-bf1942_front.jpg",
            screen_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/screen_medium/3/34737/1032047-bf1942_front.jpg",
            small_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/3/34737/1032047-bf1942_front.jpg",
            super_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_large/3/34737/1032047-bf1942_front.jpg",
            thumb_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_avatar/3/34737/1032047-bf1942_front.jpg",
            tiny_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_mini/3/34737/1032047-bf1942_front.jpg"
        },
        name: "Battlefield 1942",
        platforms: [{
            api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-17/",
            id: 17,
            name: "Mac",
            site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/mac/3045-17/",
            abbreviation: "MAC"
        }, {
            api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-94/",
            id: 94,
            name: "PC",
            site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/pc/3045-94/",
            abbreviation: "PC"
        }],
        resource_type: "game"
    }, {
        image: {
            icon_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_avatar/8/87790/1897518-box_bf2142.png",
            medium_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_medium/8/87790/1897518-box_bf2142.png",
            screen_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/screen_medium/8/87790/1897518-box_bf2142.png",
            small_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/8/87790/1897518-box_bf2142.png",
            super_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_large/8/87790/1897518-box_bf2142.png",
            thumb_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_avatar/8/87790/1897518-box_bf2142.png",
            tiny_url: "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_mini/8/87790/1897518-box_bf2142.png"
        },
        name: "Battlefield 2142",
        platforms: [{
            api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-17/",
            id: 17,
            name: "Mac",
            site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/mac/3045-17/",
            abbreviation: "MAC"
        }, {
            api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-94/",
            id: 94,
            name: "PC",
            site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/pc/3045-94/",
            abbreviation: "PC"
        }],
        resource_type: "game"
    }],
    version: "1.0"
})
```

Comment: Not relevant to jquery at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rightArray = [];    
for (game in gameArray) {
  for (con in gameArray[game]) {
    rightArray.push(game + ', ' + gameArray[game][con]);
  }
}
```